# React-table with select and dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit Note:Link with working version at bottom of post

I have run into some really weird behavior with my project
[image]

I have the parent which gets some data from a database and passes it to the child (which is a popup). The child then uses useEffect to detect when the data is ready (black part) and sets the value in the child (blue part).

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(datachannels.length)

    if (datachannels.length > 1) {
      let newValueState = []
      let c = 0
      datachannels.forEach(element => {
        newValueState.push({ id: c, dc: element.dataChannel, axis: "y" })
        c += 1
      });
      setValueState(newValueState)
      console.log(newValueState)
      console.log("trigger")
    }
  }, [datachannels])
```

Then when a user changes a option this code runs to update it(Green part)

```js
  const handler = (event, id) => {
    console.log(valueState)
    const value = event.value
    console.log(valueState.length)
    if (valueState.length > 0) {
      let newValueState = valueState
      newValueState.forEach(key => {
        if (key.id == id) {
          console.log(key)
          key.axis = value
        }
      });
      setValueState(newValueState)
    }
  }
```

With inspect i can see that the value is not empty but the handler function trying to use it is telling me its empty. When giving valueState a default value and after useEffect code runs, I try and access it but it just returns the default value. I have no idea what is causeing this or what to google so if anyone can shead some light on this, I would be very happy

Update 1: Codesandebox (new link below) I have not been able to get the bug to show yet

Update 2:Code in sandbox now has error. As you can see when useEffect runs the object has 3 values but when the user changes the dropdown it only has one value
[image]

Update 3: To see the bug in the sandbox change one of the axis drop downs

Update 4: Porok12 answer works in the sand box but is not working in my actully project and i have no idea what is going on

Update 5: So when using Porok12 code and feeding in datachannels the same way as the sandbox it does work but with some other weird behavior that im hopping can point to the problem. [image] When changing a dropdown this is outputted to the console. From `input was changed` to (3) `[{},{},{}]` is the correct behavior but then everything rerenders as seen from the other messages. I have no idea why it is behaving differently from porok12 code as it is the same. But this does point out a problem with how datachannels is being passed in? In the parent object I am storing the channels like this

```js
    if (data !== undefined) {
      let parseData = JSON.parse(data);
      let toPush = []
      Object.keys(parseData).forEach(key => {
        toPush.push({ "dataChannel": key })
      });
      setDataChannels(toPush);
```

And feeding it to the child like this `<BuilderTable handleupdate={handleUpdate} datachannels={dataChannels} show={modalShow} onHide={() => setModalShow(false)} />`

Update 6: So its now working with Porok12 code after i changed the useMemo [] to use valueState instead of datachannel. The only problem now is that the dropdown reset to the starting value every time you change it

Update 7: With the change from update 6 and feeding valueStatus into the dropdowns the problem is not fixed.

Update 8: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-water-2ucq8u?file=/src/GraphBuilderFull.js Here is the sandbox link with a working version

Comment: Try `let newValueState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(valueState))` in your handler

Comment: @Dilshan no change unfortunately

Comment: please provide more context/code (I would like to see whole components)

Comment: @Porok12 Making a codesandbox will update when i have it working

Comment: Ok, i will investigate then, because now I can only guessing

Comment: @Porok12 sandbox is now up and running https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-noether-03medv?file=/src/GraphBuilderFull.js

Comment: First thing this alert `alert(JSON.stringify(selectedRowIds, valueState))` should rather be `alert(JSON.stringify({selectedRowIds, valueState}, null, 2))` (first param is the data you want to show)

Comment: @Porok12 Yeah fair, that was from when i was building the table and figuring out how tables work. So its outdated

Comment: @ClueLess The problem was that you used `useMemo` on component that uses `handler`. I updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side note: you can change

```
let c = 0
datachannels.forEach(element => {
  newValueState.push({ id: c, dc: element.dataChannel, axis: "y" })
  c += 1
});
```

to

```
const newValueState = datachannels.map((element, index) => ({id: index, dc: element.dataChannel, axis: "y"}))
```

The problem is that you use `useMemo` that way:

```
const selectChannelTableColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Axis Selection",
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div>
            <Dropdown
              id={row.id}
              options={axis}
              onChange={(e) => handler(e, row.id)}
              placeholder="y"
            />
          </div>
        )
      }
    ],
    [] // missing `datachannels` xor `valueState` dependency
  );
```

If you will add `datachannels` to dependencies it will work. You should also move handler definition to this `useMemo` code.

[Here is fixed sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-lamport-0pf1iy?file=/src/GraphBuilderFull.js)

The changes I made:

1. Move `handler` definition to `selectChannelTableColumn` code
2. Fix `handler` logic
3. Move `selectChannelTableColumn` under (meaning below not inside) your `useEffect`
4. Add `datachannels` to `useMemo` hook dependencies

Comment: Did you make any other changes apart from in useEffect and selectChannelTableColumn. Its still not working in my main project

Comment: When copying all the code in its still broken, no idea why its working different from the sandbox

Comment: I also updated handler logic a little bit

Comment: You are still getteing this issue with wrong value in `valueState` or sth new?

Comment: Same problem, valueState just has the inital value when handler is called

Comment: I updated answer with steps i made. If you still getting the same issue this means that `selectChannelTableColumn` is not updated with proper `handler` function

Comment: Yeah not sure, my code is the same as yours but still getting the error